# Select the first character of every new paragraph in Word using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am doing Word Automation and want to select every first character of every new paragraph in Word. With my code I am able to select only first character of *only the first paragraph and not any other*. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
foreach (Word.Paragraph aPar in oWordDoc.Paragraphs) {

    Word.Range parRng = aPar.Range;
    string sText = parRng.Text;
    object startLocation5 = 2;
    object endLocation5 = 3;
    rng5 = oWordDoc.Range(ref startLocation5, ref endLocation5);
    rng5.Text = rng5.Text;
}
```

This is my document:

> fraction (mannans and xylans) to enzymatic hydrolysis.The enzymatic hydrol – ysis of crystalline lulose ,to fermentable D – glucose [71 ,74–79].
>
> The enzymatic hydrolysis of galacto(gluco)mannans ,present particularly in softwoods ,is accomplished through the action of endo – b – 1 ,4 – mannanases which randomly cleave

I want to select the 'f' and then 'T' (1st character of 2nd paragraph).

Comment: You should use *Regular Expressions* they will make it quite easy; if you Google the cheatsheet you'll actually see how to create such patterns to accomplish your goal.

Comment: 2nd para has tab space ie before "T"

Comment: http://www.remondo.net/regular-expressions-csharp-part-4-wild-character/ Refer to the example `Each_Character_Produces_Match_Except_NewLine()`